# How to print the IP address of a website in Android with InetAddress

Tags: android

How to print the IP address of a website in Android? I can run `InetAddress` and print it by using `system.out.println()` in netbean. Below is my sample coding:

```
public String getHostAddress () {
        InetAddress addr=null;
        try {
            addr= InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        }
            
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return addr.getHostAddress();
    }
```

It always shows "Unfortunately, your program has stopped."
May I know is there any way to get the IP address of the visited website in Android?

```
05-19 14:22:39.008: I/dalvikvm(1062): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-19 14:22:39.049: I/dalvikvm(1062): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-19 14:22:39.688: I/dalvikvm(1062): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-19 14:22:39.828: I/dalvikvm(1062): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-19 14:22:39.929: D/AndroidRuntime(1062): Shutting down VM
05-19 14:22:39.948: W/dalvikvm(1062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.destinationurl/com.android.destinationurl.DestinationURL}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:295)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.destinationurl.DestinationURL.getHostAddress(DestinationURL.java:57)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.destinationurl.DestinationURL.onCreate(DestinationURL.java:40)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-19 14:22:40.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     ... 11 more
05-19 14:22:40.248: I/dalvikvm(1062): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-19 14:22:40.283: I/dalvikvm(1062): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-19 14:22:40.608: I/dalvikvm(1062): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-19 14:22:40.698: I/dalvikvm(1062): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-19 14:22:42.078: I/Process(1062): Sending signal. PID: 1062 SIG: 9
```

Comment: 1. please post crash log 2. do you have the internet permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Your error is because you are trying to perform network access on main thread. See [How to Fix the Android NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://www.techblogistech.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-the-android-networkonmainthreadexception/)

Comment: Can anyone show a sample project about this issue that can work properly...thank you..=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply,

Its your mistake on URL,  Just correct it..

**"www.google.com"** you have 4 w's in your URL...

And add Use-Permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">`
 in manifest file of your android application..

This one is correct..

`addr = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");`

**EDIT:** Use `AsyncTask` for Network Operation

```
String netAddress = null;
 try
  {
   netAddress = new NetTask().execute("www.google.com").get();
  }
  catch (Exception e1)
   {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }
```

And this one is **NetTask** class..

```
public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            InetAddress addr = null;
            try
            {
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
            }

            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addr.getHostAddress();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code work perfect in my case, In main thread.. Your Logcat error pointed on NetworkOnMainThreadException so put this code in other worker thread..

Comment: To user370305: Do you have any recommended android cookbook which have a detail explanation about networking parts in android.I am craving for it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: something like how to use those java.net and android.net related commands in android.

Comment: Android is same as Java.But be careful that your Networking Communication never block your Application's main UI thread. Always done it on either worker thread or use AsyncTask. And for Android Networking just go through http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/.

Answer (score 2):

You have entered the URL wrongly with **wwww**.google.com.

```
addr= InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
```

After correction it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all the permissions you need. Maybe your application stops because it does not have proper permissions. Check if you have Internet Access permission in your XML manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are making a network call on the main thread.

```
String address = "";
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    }
});
```