# Socket error: D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Tags: android, sockets

My source code:

```
tvOut.setText("Connect...");
Log.d("my", "Connect...");
try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.121");
    Log.d("my", "InetAddress serverAddr...");
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 3426);
    Log.d("my", "socket = new Socket...");
...
```

Logcat:

12-11 00:16:36.605: D/my(1247): Connect...

12-11 00:16:36.675: D/my(1247): InetAddress serverAddr...

12-11 00:16:36.715: D/AndroidRuntime(1247): Shutting down VM

Where error?

Comment: Check the suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662805/inetaddress-in-android

Comment: socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 3426); Error in this line... Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask for network connection and take care for Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml