# InetAddress not working in android

Tags: android

I am trying to connect using InetAddress in android using button click listener
as in

```
public void onClickFindBeer(View view)
{
        TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
        try
        {
            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
            String ipAddress=inet.toString();
            brands.setText(ipAddress);
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            brands.setText(ex.getMessage());
        }

}
```

The `TextView` won't display the ip address of google
I already set the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

on manifest but still it won't display google ip address

Also logcat doesn't show anything

When I try it in java it works just fine.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662805/inetaddress-in-android

Comment: "Also logcat doesn't show anything": this is hard to believe. Are you sure there was no `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: @Henry yup I really doesn't see any error in logcat but luckily `AsyncTask` do the trick. I am using android 2.3.3